# not returning desired value from created function

Tags: c, function, casting

This is for a challenge in my lectures that i'm taking to acquire my certification in `C`. I'm running on a 64 bit system using code blocks with the mingwin gcc compiler.

The finished program will be a tic tac toe game but out of everything I have tried I am unable to get this warning to go away which also seems to not let the function I created for the program return the value I need. There also seems to not be much out there on this issue from my searching at least nothing that seems to hit close as a fix for this. I'm hoping that there is a just something simple coding wise that a beginner like myself is missing. I'm trying to keep the code I write as simple and easy to understand for myself till i get into more advanced techniques.

This is the coding I have so far and my issue is with the function `First_Move`. In that function it is giving me a warning about the return `making an integer from a pointer with out a cast` but when I provide the cast it still does not give the desired return value as to which player guessed correctly to it shows that that player is the one who goes first. The function is simply suppose to compare the players guesses to the random generated number and return the name of the player back to main that is to make the first move.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int First_Move(int g1, int g2, char p1[10], char p2[10]);

int main()
{
     char player1[10];
     char player2[10];
     int p1g;
     int p2g;
     char firstMove;

     /* The following printf(), scanf() and system() functions asks for, takes in, then stores player 1's name and then clears the
         screen for the next player.
     */
     printf("Player 1 please enter your name?\n");
     scanf("%s", player1);
     system("cls");

     /* The following printf(), scanf() and system() functions asks for, takes in, then stores player 2's name and then clears the
         screen for the next function to display text.
     */

     printf("Player 2 please enter your name?\n");
     scanf("%s", player2);
     system("cls");

     printf("To determine who goes first pick a number between 1 and 10.\n Who ever guesses correctly or is closest goes first.\n");
     printf("%s, enter your guess now.", player1);
     scanf("%i", &p1g);
     printf("%s, enter your guess now.", player2);
     scanf("%i", &p2g);

     First_Move(p1g, p2g, player1, player2);
     firstMove=First_Move(p1g, p2g, player1, player2);
     printf("The player who guessed or was closest to the number was: %c\n", firstMove);
     system("cls"),


    return 0;
}

int First_Move(int g1, int g2, char p1[10], char p2[10])
{
    long int time_t t ;
    int numberToGuess;
    int g1Difference;
    int g2Difference;


    srand((unsigned)time(&t));     //This will seed my random number generator by using the time from the machine.

    numberToGuess=rand()% 11;      //This calls the random number generator and stores the generated number in numberToGuess.
     /*
          The following printf() is to test and make sure the number generator was correctly generating random numbers and to make sure
          that the function was returning the correct value to main in relation to which player had the correct guess. This will be
          encapsulated in the this comment before finalization.
     */
    printf("%i\n", numberToGuess);

     /*
          The following series of nested if else statements goes through the process of determining if one of the players guesses
          is the same as the number generated and if not then proceeds to determine which number is closer to return which guess
          was the closest.
     */
   {
    if(g1==numberToGuess)
     return (char *)p1;
    else
     if(g2==numberToGuess)
     return p2;
    else
     if(numberToGuess>g1)
          g1Difference=numberToGuess-g1;
          else
               g1Difference=g1-numberToGuess;
     if(numberToGuess>g2)
          g2Difference=numberToGuess-g2;
          else
               g2Difference=g2-numberToGuess;
   }
     if(g1Difference<g2Difference)
          return p1;
          else
               return p2;
}
```

Comment: Sorry I completely forgot the question. I edited it putting in the question.

Comment: RE: "I have tried I am unable to get this warning to go away"... What warning... specifically (e.g. show the compiler warning)

Comment: the warning is return makes integer from pointer without a cast but when i do cast it still doesn't work and I get a different warning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I see a couple things:

```
system("cls"),
```

should be

```
system("cls");
```

(actually, you should remove this call, as it clears the screen immediately and you cannot see the results of `First_Move()`)

and

```
long int time_t t;
```

this should just be

```
time_t t;
```

and

```
First_Move(p1g, p2g, player1, player2);
firstMove = First_Move(p1g, p2g, player1, player2);
```

The first call to `First_Move()` should be removed.

As to your pointer cast warning,  `First_Move()` is supposed to return an `int`, but you are always returning `char` arrays signifying which player was closer.  Personally, I would not even pass in the player names (they are never used in the function) and just have `First_Move()` return either `1` or `2`, signifying which player won.  And then call `First_Move()` via

```
if (First_Move(p1g, p2g) == 1) {
    printf("The player who guessed or was closest to the number was: %s\n", player1);
} else {
    printf("The player who guessed or was closest to the number was: %s\n", player2);
}
```

Your approach is a cool idea, and would be useful if your situation was more complicated, but for choosing between `player1` and `player2`, I think it complicates `First_Move()` more than needed.  Also, if you need to know later in your code which player won `First_Move()`, it is more efficient to check the value of an `int` than a string.

Unless of course, some part of the assignment says it must be done your way?  If so, then I would simply change the return value of `First_Move()` from `int` to `char *`.

Comment: So have first move return a boolean value based on the outcome of the series of nested if else statements. is that correct.

Comment: I think an integer would be clearer than a boolean, but either would work since you have two players.  Use the same code, but everywhere you return `p1`, instead return `1` and everywhere you return `p2` return `2`.

Comment: I will let you know if that works. now after starting to make more changes the compiler is actually not compiling now because of 2 errors with random number generator that it was fine with before. I will get back to you on the topic at hand as soon as figure out why this is being a pain now all the sudden.

Comment: Ok the random number generator is fixed and I ran the program several times with it also showing the number that was generated and the whole thing is working with just returning either 1 or 2 to the main and using that in the if statements to show the player name that is going first. Thank you so much Stephen Docy. I will mark this as the answer. Out of curiosity I wasn't trying to overload the function with to many data types was I. When the program is complete I will shoot a link to fork it from my github account so you can see the final product you help me create by figuring out this issue.

Comment: Thanks !!  Like I said, there was nothing really wrong with your approach (except getting the function return values wrong) and under different circumstances it could be useful.  But to pass in the string names only for the purpose of passing them back as a return value just seemed a little overly complex.

Comment: Ya i have that habit of making things more complex than it needs to be when its new to me. lol

Answer (score 1):

Lots of "lessons to learn" here, but lets start with:

```
char firstMove;
firstMove=First_Move(p1g, p2g, player1, player2); // char = int - that's bad!
```

And then

```
int First_Move(int g1, int g2, char p1[10], char p2[10])
{
    ...
    return (char *)p1; // but we're supposed to be returning an int
```

So perhaps the "easy answer" is the `First_Move` is supposed to return a `char*`...